# has_and_belongs_to_many with join table and checkbox collection

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to make an admin page that has a nested form for another model.

I have a Playbook model:

**playbook.rb**

```
  has_and_belongs_to_many :groups
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :groups
```

my form view

**_form.html.haml**

```
<%= form_with(model: playbook, local: true) do |form| %>

   ...

  <%= collection_check_boxes(:group, :group_ids, Group.all, :id, :name) %>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= form.submit %>
  </div>
```

To explain it more, playbooks can have many groups which are another model and I want to save to the groups_playbooks join table automatically when saving the playbook using what I think would be a nested form. I just dont know how to do the nested form with a collection of checkboxes like my view.

Here is part of schema to help give a better picture:

```
  create_table "groups", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.string "variables"
    t.bigint "server_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.index ["server_id"], name: "index_groups_on_server_id"
  end

  create_table "groups_playbooks", id: false, force: :cascade do |t|
    t.bigint "group_id", null: false
    t.bigint "playbook_id", null: false
  end

  create_table "groups_servers", id: false, force: :cascade do |t|
    t.bigint "group_id", null: false
    t.bigint "server_id", null: false
  end

  create_table "playbooks", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.string "play"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.string "description"
  end

  create_table "playbooks_servers", id: false, force: :cascade do |t|
    t.bigint "playbook_id", null: false
    t.bigint "server_id", null: false
  end

  create_table "servers", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.string "ip"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.bigint "group_id"
    t.index ["group_id"], name: "index_servers_on_group_id"
  end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [specification](https://apidock.com/rails/v4.0.2/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/collection_check_boxes) you should use `playbook` instead of `groups`

```
<%= collection_check_boxes(:playbook, :group_ids, Group.all, :id, :name) %>
```

But as you have the form builder you should look on [that specification](https://apidock.com/rails/v4.0.2/ActionView/Helpers/FormBuilder/collection_check_boxes)

For your case

```
<%= form.collection_check_boxes(:group_ids, Group.all, :id, :name) %>
```